# How many combinations can i get if the random word use's

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations can i get if the random word use's

10 characters long 
Numeric digits (0-9)
Uppercase letters (A-Z)
Lowercase letters (a-z)

and Each string should be unique

Comment: This is off-topic as it does not contain anything related to programming

Comment: 10 numbers and 52 letters, 10 char long, non repeated: 107518933731

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, and therefore belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a program to go through all the combinations. Here is an example in python:

```
import itertools
combos=itertools.permutations(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','a','b'....])
for combo in combos: print combo
```

From a mathematical perspective, I believe its 62^10